# add class to audio tag "programmatically"?

Tags: jquery, audio

I am creating audio, assigning a source to it and appending it to the page programmatically with jquery, i also need to add a class to this audio, however i cant make it work, i tried this:

```
var song = new Audio();
song.src = data[random].stream_url + client; //src is taken from api


$("#audioWrapper").append("<ul><li>" +data[random].title +"</li></ul>").append(song);
song.addClass("muzz");
```

it's giving me an undefined error, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`song` is `DOM` element not jQuery Object so you can't use `.addClass()` to it.

you can do `$(song).addClass("muzz")`.

`$(song)` --> jQuery Object

```
$("#audioWrapper")
    .append("<ul><li>Test</li></ul>")
    .append($(song).addClass("muzz"));
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/8nDFj/)</kbd>

Comment: ohhhh, herp derp, thank you so much! will accept answer in  9 minutes